# How to make Masonry / Instagram Explore Feed like gallery with css?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am stuck with this, help pls.

I know I could do it with css flexbox, just by using bootstrap's "row", "col-6", "col-4", and etc, but I want to keep things simple, without any extra wrappers. And CSS Grid is the solution, but I don't understand how to do it like on design.

I need to make this gallery layout.
[image: PC version of gallery]

Also it's responsive, and should look like that on mobile:

[image]

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 30px;
  grid-column-gap: 30px;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div class="grid__item"><img src="https://demo.phpgang.com/crop-images/demo_files/pool.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: [Demo](https://jsbin.com/dewusagofa/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: @Yousaf awesome! thanks bro!